# How to update a project using iron-ajax from polymer 1 to polymer 3

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a webapp that I created in polymer 1 that uses iron-ajax to get data from the server.  I am going to be redoing the webapp in polymer 3 and would like to know. Should I still use iron-ajax or is there a better resource to use?

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was looking for.  Can you repost this as an answer rather than a comment?  That way, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iron-ajax` has been upgraded to polymer 3, it works just fine with polymer 3 why to replace it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [native Fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```

Or external libraries such as [axios](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/axios)